# Can't use new methods in the Android project due to minSdkVersion

Tags: java, android, api, version

I want to support API Level 14+ devices, so **minSdkVersion** of my android project is "14" now.

But I can't call newer methods, even though I put those code in `if` statements.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
    // new method calls
    Log.i("MY_APP", "Total: " + new StatFs("/sdcard").getTotalBytes());
} else {
    // deprecated method calls
}
```

And `<uses-sdk/>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml is this.

```
<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="14"
   android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

The error message is like this.

> Call requires API level 18 (current min is 14):
>   android.os.StatFs#getTotalBytes

In order to compile this project, I have to change **minSdkVersion** attribute

but this doesn't help at all, because I lose support for older devices.

I tried adjusting **targetSdkVersion** too, but this doesn't work.

How can I compile my project without changing minSdkVersion?

**Do I have to use deprecated methods only?**

**Is there any chances for deprecated methods to be removed soon?**

PS. I'm using eclipse but not Android Studio now.

Comment: Can I just check, what is your target SDK Version?

Comment: You have to set your `targetSDKVersion`

Comment: Ah, does it have something to do with that? I'll check it out! thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it!!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. Your code snippet is not helpful, as we have no idea what method(s) you are trying to call, what your various build settings are (e.g., `minSdkVersion`, `compileSdkVersion`).

Comment: Ah.... I was really stupid. I'm using Eclipse at the moment and had to be more careful. Eclipse was giving me the solution already. Changing targetSDKVersion didn't help but adding @SuppressLint("NewApi") solved the problem. Thank you all!

Comment: Didn't help. I had to put @SuppressLint("NewApi")..

Comment: @JenixGuy ok, congrats on solving your issue though, Eclipse will give you hints as to what is wrong with your code, just like Visual Studio does with intellisense.

Comment: Right. Should be more careful.. Thanks, have a good one! :)

Answer (score 2):

Modify your gradle file to look something like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23 // for example
    // other stuff...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Set targetSdkVersion to the highest API on which app has been tested. Keep targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion the same.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so you said you are using Eclipse (please change it already to Android Studio! :)) so you can use these in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk 
      android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm using eclipse :)

Comment: Edited the answer, I hope that helps!

Comment: You might not have seen my comment above yet. I solved the problem putting @SuppressLint("NewApi") in front of my class or method declaration. Thanks anyway!